# First 50% total value

Tags: sql

I want to get the data where the summation of value lesser than or equal to the 50% of total value.

Here is an example:

```
name          Score
mike          1000
robert        900
scott         500
jack          500
tina          500
albert        500
jose          500
arnel         300
john          200
kelly         200
george        100
sophia        50
```

If I sum all their scores I get 5250 and the 50% of the total is 2625. I need to get the score within the 50% of total score:

```
name          Score      summation    condition
mike          1000        1000          true
robert        900         1900          true
scott         500         2400          true
jack          500         2900          false
tina          500         3400          false
albert        500         3900          false
jose          500         4400          false
arnel         300         4700          false
john          200         4900          false
kelly         200         5100          false
george        100         5200          false
sophia        50          5250          false
```

All the condition true will be the output.

**NOTE:** the score must be order to highest to lowest number.

I have this code.

```
   select name, score
   from
       (
       select name, SUM(a.score) over (order by score desc) sumvalues, score
       from dbo.tally_count a
       ) as x
   where sumvalues <= (select sum(score) * 0.5 from tally_count)
```

but it only returns mike and robert.

Comment: You are looking for cumulative sum.

Comment: which db/version are you using?

Comment: can you give a example of the cumulative  sum.

Comment: You need an id column or similar to order the rows. (Or by name.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your query is that it is not doing the cumulative sum as you want as there are multiple `names` with same `score`. 
 If you run your inner query, you will get this output

`select name, SUM(a.score) over (order by score desc) sumvalues, score from tally_count a`

`Output`

```
NAME  SUMVALUES SCORE
mike    1000    1000
robert  1900    900
tina    4400    500
jack    4400    500
scott   4400    500
albert  4400    500
jose    4400    500
arnel   4700    300
john    5100    200
kelly   5100    200
george  5200    100
sophia  5250    50
```

If you want the output in the order you gave, you need to insert a column to determine the order. I used a column say `skey`. So for `mike`, `skey` = `1`, for `robert` it is `2` and so on.

`select name, SUM(a.score) over (order by score desc,skey) sumvalues, score from tally_count a`

`output`

```
NAME  SUMVALUES SCORE
mike    1000    1000
robert  1900    900
scott   2400    500
jack    2900    500
tina    3400    500
albert  3900    500
jose    4400    500
arnel   4700    300
john    4900    200
kelly   5100    200
george  5200    100
sophia  5250    50
```

Now use your remaining query to get the desired output.

Note: The query I tried is in Oracle but the syntax is more or less the same. Please change it accordingly as per your db.